# Consecutive - in a YAML file

Tags: yaml, serverless

While going through serverless basic setup, I came across a YAML file that has two consecutive `-` in the definition.
Following is the YAML

```
# serverless.yml
service: myService
provider:
  name: aws
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:ListBucket'
          # You can put CloudFormation syntax in here.  No one will judge you.
          # Remember, this all gets translated to CloudFormation.
          Resource: { 'Fn::Join': ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', { 'Ref': 'ServerlessDeploymentBucket' }]] }
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:PutObject'
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - 'Ref': 'ServerlessDeploymentBucket'
                - '/*'

functions:
  functionOne:
    handler: handler.functionOne
    memorySize: 512
```

Here we can see that in `- - 'arn:aws:s3:::'` there are two consecutive `-`. Can somebody help me understand what does that mean?

I'm referring to https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning of `- -`; both dashes act according to their general semantics:

A `-` starts a YAML sequence item. Sibling sequence items at the same indentation level form a sequence. So, this is a sequence consisting of two sequence items:

```yaml
- a
- b
```

Now the *content* of a sequence item is any valid YAML node. A sequence is a valid YAML node. Thus, this is allowed:

```yaml
- a
- - b
  - c
```

This YAML document is a sequence with two items, the first one being a scalar `a`, the second one being a nested sequence with two items, the scalars `b` and `c`. YAML calls this *compact notation* because the usual notation would be

```yaml
- a
- 
  - b
  - c
```

This longer notation allows giving the nested sequence an anchor (e.g. `&a`), a tag (e.g. `!!seq`) or both at its header line. Those are rather exotic features that are seldom used, and if don't need them, you can use the compact notation instead, which leads to two `- -`.